# No xpath click in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I've written a "Lovoo" bot with Python and Selenium and I'm almost done.

Now I have the following problem:

[image]

When the bot clicks on a user, a window opens. To exit this window, the bot has to click outside of it.

But from that point on all the source code has changed and I have nowhere to xpath or click with selenium. I simply can't get any xpath that works.

I tried

```
WebDriverWait(DRIVER,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//body[1]')))

DRIVER.find_element_by_xpath('//body[1]).click()
```

But the click is only working randomly and rarely.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-square u-margin-0">...</div> is not clickable at point (370, 497). Other element would receive the click: <div class="absolute-fill text-left" ng-transclude=""></div>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.9)
```

I don't want to use

```
action.click()
```

because then I won't be able to use my mouse for other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it clearly, you are trying to `click` on `co-ordinate` rather than a `web element`.

If this is the case then you can define an offset like below and try to click on it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(10,10).click().perform()
```

Comment: It works but I have another question. When I minimize the browser, it's not working. Can you help me with that too?

Comment: How do you minimize the browser ?

Comment: I just click minimize :D

Comment: Why do you want to minimize the windows? If you do not wish to have a GUI mode execution, Please use headless mode.